# Drupal - Feed Link Inside Tabbed Mini-Panels Go Wild

Tags: javascript, drupal, rss, feed, panels

A panel page created by two tabbed mini-panels using customized views of feedapi.  http://arisey.com/template

The feed link goes to the right external website in mini-panel view. However in the combined panel view, the feeds went wild and pointed to non-existing internal links, i.e arisey.com/template#ui-tabs-124.  The html source code seems to point to the right link path, but the feeds do not behave right.  Which modules need to be modified - tabs, tabs panel style, feedapi, views, panels, mini-panels, aggregator... to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is purely a js problem. It seems highly likely that it's the javascript you use to generate the tab effect that caused this. With js disabled all the links work just fine. Looking at what the links are being recreated to, it looks very much like the work of jQuery UI tabs, look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-idPrefix).

- It seems like too many of your links are being targeted by the script, so you either have to fix the script/markup so that only the right links are being made into "tabs".
- Another solution could be to let the js handle redirecting, however that seems like a more difficult solution.

Good luck debugging.